# Having issues/problem with the if else statement

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having issues with my `if else` statement. I was trying to test the code and put it to trigger earlier than 12 in the afternoon and it's not working. I also tried to put the `(hour == 11)` and it wasn't changing from "good morning" either.

```js
const hour = new Date().getHours();
let greeting;

if (hour < 18) {
    greeting = "Good Morning!"
} else if (hour > 10) {
    greeting = "Good Afternnon!"
} else {
    greeting = "Good Evening!"
}

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = greeting;

document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 id="demo">Good Evening</h1>

    <br><br>

    <p id="time"></p>

    <script src="w3school.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While `hour < 18` is truthy, the else clause will never be executed

Comment: Your second `if` checks for a value `> 10`, but the first check will also match for eg `11`. YOu should use another order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like the following:

```
const hour = new Date().getHours();
let greeting = "Good Evening!";

if (hour < 12) {
    greeting = "Good Morning!"
} else if (hour < 18) {
    greeting = "Good Afternoon!"
}
```